# How to display additional column in select with true/false value [SOLVED]

Tags: postgresql, join

**Solved. Look in comment.**

I am using PostgreSQL 9.1. I have 3 tables:

- simcards: 
  id serial NOT NULL,
  iccid character varying(30) NOT NULL,
  customer_id integer
- customer: 
  id serial NOT NULL,
  name character varying(50) NOT NULL
- topup: 
  id serial NOT NULL,
  amount integer NOT NULL,
  iccid_id integer NOT NULL

And now when I select some simcards I would like to get extra column that shows value yes/no, true/false, 1/0 if this simcard has also a record in topup table (if had been toped up).

I think I have to use LEFT JOIN but I don't know how to display only value true/false. Here is my current SQL that shows everything form topup table:

```
select
   b.iccid,
   b.phone_number,
   d.name as customer,
   t.*
from
   simcard_simcard as b
   join simcard_customer as d
       on b.customer_id = d.id   
   left join simcard_topup as t
    on b.id = t.iccid_id
where d.name = 'THREE'
```

Can you give me any suggestions?
Thanks

Comment: replace `t.*` with `t.id IS NOT NULL`. That should return `true` if it's not null (it exists) and `false` otherwise.

Comment: Thanks! Works great! I knew it would be something simple, but I couldn't figure this out. Thanks again.